# Embedding a 3-D editor (such as Blender) in a wxPython application

Tags: python, 3d, wxpython, embedding, blender

Is it possible to embed a 3-D editor inside my wxPython application? (I'm thinking Blender, but other suggestions are welcome.)

My application opens a wxPython window, and I want to have a 3-D editor inside of it. Of course, I want my program and the 3-D editor to interact with each other.

Possible? How?

Comment: When you say 'interact with', what were you hoping to do with it?

Comment: For example, that my program will be able to change the positions of bodies in the 3-d world. Also, if I drag a body inside the 3-D editor, I want it to report this action to my program, with the new position.

Answer (score 2):

Blender has python plugins, you can write a plugin to interract with your program.

Comment: http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-3098.html and http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-3336.html discuss using sockets to communicate between Blender instances, something similar could be done easily between Python and Blender

Comment: But in this scenario, will Blender still be its own window, or will it be inside my program's window? I'm aiming for the latter.

Comment: It would be a separate window/application

Answer (score 1):

I second Luper Rouch's idea of Blender plugins. But if you must have your own window you need to fork Blender. Take a look at [makehuman](http://www.makehuman.org/) project. It used to have Blender as a platform. (I'm not sure but I think they have a different infrastructure now)

Answer (score 0):

For [Blender](http://www.blender.org) specifically, I doubt it. Blender uses a custom UI based on OpenGL, and I'm not sure you can force it to use a pre-existing window. I suggest browsing the code of "Ghost", which is Blender's custom adaption layer (responsible for interacting with the OS for UI purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this script](http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1122&sid=3547dbaaf0e412da6ab510870c44ebf7) might provide some context for your project. It integrates Blender, ActiveX, and wxPython.

Caveat: Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

For Blender2.5 on linux you can use gtk.Socket, code example is [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vYtJmmAC)

Comment: Welcome on SO. Since it's not too long, I suggest that you paste the relevant part in. You can do that by using the "edit" link button below your post. :)